# undefined symbol error when trying to assemble a MASM assembly file

Tags: assembly, x86, visual-studio-2019, masm

I'm trying to write the following in x86 MASM assembly, in visual studio 2019:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION_struct= dword ptr -B0h
STARTUPINFO_struct= dword ptr- A0h
```

But i'm getting the following error(s):

```
Error   A2006   undefined symbol : A0h
Error   A2006   undefined symbol : B0h
```

Thing is, it only happens when I write a hex letter at the beggining of a number. If, for instance, I had written `90h`, it works just fine.

In the project dependancies I added the Microsoft Macro Assembler, and set the file to be assembled using the Microsoft Macro Assembler, if that helps.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Add a leading zero. Most x86 assemblers do not recognise parameters starting with letters as hexadecimal numbers, so if you want to enter a number like that you have to write eg `0B0h`

Comment: Yep, figured it. But thanks!